# link cell text to file of the same name

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba, hyperlink

i have a workbook in excel and in one column i am putting the names of images.

i want to create a macro/vba code so that when i type in the file name into the column e.g. IMG_1234 it will automatically be hyperlinked to a file such as file:///\public\Pictures\IMG_1234.JPG

Then when someone clicks on the link it will load a new window with the picture displayed.

I have found some code that answers my question in a Macro...however I wonder if it is possible to do this so it updates automatically rather than having to run the Macro every time...

```
Sub PictureLink()

MyPath = "\\\public\Pictures\"
StartRow = 8
EndRow = 200
MyEnd = ".JPG"

x = 0

For i = StartRow To EndRow
    If Len(Cells(i, 4).Value) > 0 Then
        MyFileName = ""
        MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & Cells(i, 4).Text & MyEnd, vbNormal + vbDirectory)

        If MyFileName <> "" Then
            x = x + 1
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 4), _
                        Address:=MyPath & Cells(i, 4).Text & MyEnd
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Hopefully someone can help me to modify this so it does it automatically.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your macro like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  ' your code here
End Sub
```

and use `Target` to access the cell.

Comment: so will that automatically hyperlink the text as soon as a valid picture name is typed in the cell?

Comment: It will try to hyperlink each changed cell, so you'll have to add some validation checks to your code to make sure that a hyperlink is only added when the value actually is an existing picture.

Comment: how do i use target to access the cell?

Comment: worked it out now - wasn't putting the code into the sheets private function area! working perfectly now and with the code i put above only hyperlinks if there is a valid picture in the file! thanks